# Regular Expression to extract inner text from anchor tags along with inner html tags

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to extract inner text from anchor tags along with inner html tags from Regular expression.I have tried but not able to found. I have provided the sample structure below.

My Regular Expression is this: (class="related-article"(?:\s|\n)*)href="(.*?)"(>(.*?))"

I need to match my regular expression (  tag ) from the below html content:

```
<a class="related-article" href="10.1182/blood-2017-11-812990">
                 <i>Blood</i> Commentary</a> on this article in this issue.</p>
```

Comment: Probably easier to just use JSoup or something similar and parse the HTML.

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen Without using JSoup is it possible to match my regular expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2979473

Answer (score 2):

## [Don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2979473).

If you want to extract data from HTML, use **XPath**.

#### [Using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

(Tag in your question suggests Java. Or did you mean Javascript?)

#### Your problem will look something like this:

I am not a Java user, instead I program in C#, so please take this code as a pseudocode direction suggestion rather than copy-paste compiling example.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//p/a[@class='related-article']");
NodeList list = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
foreach(Node node in list)
{
    string text = node.InnerText;
    string href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following helpful:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public static void main(String[]) {
   String sample = "<!---DOCTYPE><html><body></body></html>";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(sample); 
   while (m.find()) {
      String group = m.group(1);
      if (group.contains("!") {
         continue;
      }
      System.out.print(group);
   }  
}
```

Returns: `htmlbody/body/html`